# How to extract the Sql Command from a Compiled Linq Query

Tags: linq-to-sql, sqlcommand, compiled-query

In normal (not compiled) Linq to Sql queries you can extract the SQLCommand from the IQueryable via the following code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = (SqlCommand)table.Context.GetCommand(query);
```

Is it possible to do the same for a compiled query?

The following code provides me with a delegate to a compiled query:

```
        private static readonly Func<Data.DAL.Context, string, IQueryable<Word>> Query_Get =
        CompiledQuery.Compile<Data.DAL.Context, string, IQueryable<Word>>(
            (context, name) =>
                from r in context.GetTable<Word>()
                where r.Name == name
                select r);
```

When i use this to generate the IQueryable and attempt to extract the SqlCommand it doesn't seem to work. When debugging the code I can see that the SqlCommand returned has the 'very' useful CommandText of '**SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]**'

```
        using (var db = new Data.DAL.Context())
        {
            IQueryable<Word> query = Query_Get(db, "word");
            SqlCommand cmd = (SqlCommand)db.GetCommand(query);
            Console.WriteLine(cmd != null ? cmd.CommandText : "Command Not Found");
        }
```

I can't find anything in google about this particular scenario, as no doubt it is not a common thing to attempt...

So.... Any thoughts?

Comment: Ever find anything out?  I'm up against the same challenge.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the DataContext log:

```
db.Log = Console.Out;
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be a way from .NET, but you can profile your SQL Server database and capture the SQL sent to it. You can do this from SQL Management Studio.